# Parameters not making it to the controller to filter results rendered by ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out why my parameters from a view aren't making it to another controller and filtering the results in the controller. No matter what I enter into the view textbox fields I get all results. I am trying to filter the results the controller will provide for the other view. I am new to MVC and have looked all day to try and figure this out and I am not having any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

> 1. I want the "Input" view to asked these three questions.
> 2. On submit, these parameters are passed to the controller and the controller filters the results sent to the "Index" view.
> 3. The Input view in in the same folder as the Index view

**Input View**

```
        Year: @Html.TextBox("Year")
        Quarter: @Html.TextBox("Qtr")
        Division: @Html.TextBox("Div")
        @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "Index", "DivisionIncomeController", new
        { Year = ViewBag.Year, Qtr = ViewBag.Qtr, Div = ViewBag.Div, })
```

**Controller**

```
         public class DivisionIncomeController : Controller
         {
           private ProjectionsEntities db = new ProjectionsEntities();

           // GET: DivisionIncome
           public ActionResult Index(int? Year, int? Qtr, string Div)
            {
               var data = db.JobRecaps.AsQueryable();
               if (Year.HasValue)
               data = data.Where(x => x.Year == Year);
               if (Qtr.HasValue)
               data = data.Where(x => x.Qtr == Qtr);
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Div))
               data = data.Where(x => x.Div == Div);

              return View(data.ToList());
           }
```

**RouteConfig**

```
          routes.MapRoute(
             name: "DivisionIncomeControllerIndex",
             url: "{DivisionIncomeController}/{Index}/{Year}/{Qtr}/{Div}",
             defaults: new { controller = "DivisionIncomeController", action = "Index" }
         );
```

**Model**

```
     public partial class JobRecap
     {
        public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Job_ID { get; set; }
       public int Year { get; set; }
       public int Qtr { get; set; }
       public string Div { get; set; }
       public string PreparedBy { get; set; }
       public string ReviewedBy { get; set; }
       public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
       public Nullable<System.DateTime> ProjStart { get; set; }
       public Nullable<System.DateTime> ProjComp { get; set; }
       public string SvgsSplit { get; set; }
       public Nullable<int> OwnerSplit { get; set; }
       public Nullable<int> BSSplit { get; set; }
       public string JointVent { get; set; }
       public Nullable<int> BSPct { get; set; }
       public string ContractType { get; set; }
       public string ContractWritten { get; set; }
       public Nullable<decimal> CurContrAmt { get; set; }
       public string FeeBasis { get; set; }
       public Nullable<decimal> EstTotFeePct { get; set; }
       public Nullable<decimal> EstTotFeeAmt { get; set; }
```

Comment: All you have shown in the view is a `@Html.ActionLink()` which will send the initial `ViewBag` values to the controller. You need a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` helper method generates an anchor tag and clicking on that will usually issue a **GET** request. The route values you are using with the anchor tag is read from ViewBag (and razor will render the value of that in the page). So when user changes something in the input fields, It will not updated the ViewBag or the query string of the anchor tag *unless you do some workarounds  with javascript*.

What you should do is keep the input fields in the [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) and use a submit button to post it to server.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index"," DivisionIncome",FormMethod.Get))
{
   <input type="text" name="Year" value="@ViewBag.Year" />
   <input type="text" name="Qtr" value="@ViewBag.Qtr" />
   <input type="text" name="Div" value="@ViewBag.Div" />
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

In the above code, since we are explicitly specifying the form method to be `GET`, when you post the form by clicking on the submit button, the browser will issue a **GET** request to `DivisionIncome/Index?Year=2004&Qtr=11&Div=someValue` and the values posted will be mapped to the parameters of your action method.

*The values for `Year`,`Qtr` and `Div` in the query string will be what you have in the input field. I just hard coded for explaining.*

If you do not want those to be part of the URL, You may use a [different overload of BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29) method which accepts only the action name and controller name. This overload uses the default form method which is `POST`. When `POST` is used as the form method, The form element values will be posted as part of the request body instead of the url.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","DivisionIncome"))
{
   <input type="text" name="Year" value="@ViewBag.Year" />
   <input type="text" name="Qtr" value="@ViewBag.Qtr" />
   <input type="text" name="Div" value="@ViewBag.Div" />
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I believe I am getting closer. Now I am getting an error <404> . It says"The controller for path &#39;/ DivisionIncomeController&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.

Comment: I have gotten this error before while trying to find a solution but don't really understand how to fix this either.

Comment: I have figured it out. I had a syntax error! Thank you Shyju for your answer! Works great!!